# Exact Url match in apache redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a rewrite that needs be matched like below.

```
/test          ---No Match and no redirect
/test/         ---No Match and no redirect
/test/*        --Match and redirect. It should match only for this.
```

I have written a redirect rule that is matching for above all ocuurances.

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.+)$ http://test.se/abcd/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Please suggest that the above rule matches only for /test/anytext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule you have is what you want, except since it's in an htaccess file (I assume), you need to get rid of that leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ http://test.se/abcd/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

And make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded and the rewrite engine turned on:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also the redirect rule taht I have to write to match only /test and /test/ to /home/mytest/index.html

Comment: @Patan You mean something like `RewriteRule ^test/?$ /home/mytest/index.html [L]`?

Comment: Thanks you. now we have the same rule in our production. It also redirects /test and /test/ to http://test.se/abcd/index.html. I am not sure if there is any other rule causing this.can you help me here.